# The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, eclipse, browser

While running my eclipse I received this error. But when I run my project it is executed in the internal browser. But it is not executed in the default system web browser. Any one answer for this. Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: Need more details. Where is the error happening, what did you do? What kind of project, what kind of server? OS? Screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

You may change browser setting from `eclipse` -

**Window->Web Browser-> Now select your browser**

Comment: while setting that only am receiving the error as "The directory name, file name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes when you change the .html or .jsp file to text file or some other file type which is not read by web container.

In my case i had .jsp/html files changed to text format.

I changed the file types:

1) right click on file from folder where you files are located
2) open file properties
3) change the "open with" to your default web-browser (chrome,mozila,IE)
4) Apply ok

Go to eclipse and run your project...

Comment: bro. you save my 1 year problem. i always find how to solve it. but there is no perfect simple answers in eclips. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Even if I tried every suggestion, I have could not overcome that issue at first. In my case, **delete the tomcat installation** folder (for me C:/tomcat), then **installing tomcat** again solved my problem. May be you are confused while other settings, too.

Answer (score 0):

I set another browser as the default browser and it work for me.

Steps for windows-
settings->default app->(the required browser)->set as default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried to attach the images but I am the new user so it didn't allow me. But thanks for the reference.